# Why doesn't my asynchronous write function run?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, irc

Ok, so I've been making an asynchronous IRC and it works fine except for one issue. The client can write and the server can read. Except the server can't write and the client can't read. Any help?

https://github.com/theprogrammer4568/IRC

```
        async public static Task Receive()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

                int data = await Server.stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                string message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, data);

                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }


        async public static Task Send()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

                string message = Console.ReadLine();
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                await Server.stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }

        async static Task Async()
        {
            await Task.Run(Read.Receive);
            await Task.Run(Write.Send);
        }
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: What is the purpose of your `Bytes` variable?

Comment: https://github.com/theprogrammer4568/IRC

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, I'm new to StackOverflow. But I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Send` function never runs, because your `Receive` function loops forever.

Even though you are running them on different threads with `Task.Run()`, you are still `await`ing the result of `Receive` before running `Send`.